# Ability to connect Magento to existing database?

Tags: magento

I have an existing database that contains 4 tables: categories, sub-categories, products, prices.  I am looking to create an ecom site using Magento leveraging the existing tables.  I would rather not import the tables since products will be continually modified.  I am new to Magento.   What is the best way to handle this?  Would I want to query my existing tables and hook into Magento bypassing their product tables?  Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're choosing the wrong e-commerce system if want to use your existing database in place of the one in Magento. Magento doesn't work like this. You can't have the Magento interface and not the guts of it. They are inextricably bound (some would say, tightly coupled).

I would hire a Magento programmer and have him or her create a module for you to import your products into the Magento catalog. This module should be able to handle updates to your existing database. This can be done easily as the Magento catalog model uses the entity-attribute-value (EAV) database model pattern. Then you can continue using your database.

Comment: David, thanks for your reply.  That makes sense - creating an external module to sync the non-Magento and Magento tables.  I am a PHP/MySQL programmer and I am just starting to familiarize myself with the Magento architecture by reading the “Magento for Developers” series in www.magentocommerce.com.  Do you have any other suggestions on where to look online get myself up to speed to start creating this module?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Go to http://alanstorm.com/ for a quick start. Find a quick tutorial on how to create a module. After that, it's basically just knowing where everything is, the XML configuration, the two step view process, and how to extend core Magento modules. If you've a strong OO, design patterns, Java or Zend Framework background, you should have no problem seeing a method to the madness.

Comment: Ok great, thanks - I'm checking it out. One other question, should the Magento tables be installed within the existing database or should there be two separate databases - one the existing db and the other the Magento db?  Thanks again!

Comment: I would put them all in one database. This is for simplicity's sake as the module is going to have to read/write from Magento's tables as well as your tables. This is also to avoid messing with MySQL connections. I would also give my tables a logical prefix like mycompany_tablename.